# Using JQuery to display different image based item hovered

Tags: menu, hover, jsfiddle, interactive

I'm trying to accomplish two things:

Left Column: Steps are faded by default, but individual steps fade in to full color on hover.

Right Column: A different image is displayed based on the step being hovered in the left column. By default, the first image should be displayed.

I am using the fadeIn function, but I cant get it to work the way I'm hoping. Whats the best way to go about doing this?

**[Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n26h5e4v/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#step-one')
.hover(
    function() {
        $('#step-one-image-holder').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('#step-one-image-holder').fadeOut('fast');
    }
);

$('#step-two')
.hover(
    function() {
        $('#step-two-image-holder').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('#step-two-image-holder').fadeOut('fast');
    }
);

$('#step-three')
.hover(
    function() {
        $('#step-three-image-holder').fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('#step-three-image-holder').fadeOut('fast');
    }
);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you use "hover" the images will disappear always when you leave the left column (I not sure if you want it). You may use "fadeIn" and "fadeOut" inside a "mouseenter" event:

(Maybe you need to put the images on absolute position to avoid the flickering)

```
//---Show images on mouseenter
$("div[id^='step-']").on("mouseenter", function(){

    var image = $("img[id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "-image-holder']");

    $("img[id^='step-']").not(image).fadeOut();

    image.fadeIn();    

});

//---Hide images by default
$("img[id^='step-']:gt(0)").hide();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n26h5e4v/2/)